# Customization text in html

Tags: css

```css
ul.bs-pagination {
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 18px;
}

ul.bs-pagination a {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #cc092f;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

ul.bs-pagination a:hover {
  border-color: #cc092f;
}
```

```html
<nav class="bs-pagination__nav" aria-label="Paginação">
  <ul class="bs-pagination">1<a href="p0/IZ7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2=CZ6_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK800I3=MKJTMIKw=GD=/#Z7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2" title="Link para a página 2" id="pc1617018954514_linkToPage_2">2</a><a href="p0/IZ7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2=CZ6_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK800I3=MKJTMIKw=GE=/#Z7_819E19820H3TB0Q3I25JK808F2"
      title="Link para a página 3" id="pc1617018954514_linkToPage_3">3</a> </ul>
</nav>
```

[image]
The sequence 1 2 3 above is how it should be and the one below is like it should be ...

I have an html element, where I want to add a css customization to it, but it is not between span, it has no class and id. It is simply a text inside a div, can I style it?

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid. `<ul>` can only have `<li>` child and not direct text nodes

Comment: There is no `div` in your example code, so your question ("It is simply a text inside a div,") is completely unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply your styles directly to ul parameter and the next you can write separated styles for links.

```
ul.bs-pagination {color: red;} - it's for 1
ul.bs-pagination > a {color: blue;} - it's for 2 and 3
```

```css
ul.bs-pagination {
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0px 2px;
    min-width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
}
ul.bs-pagination a {
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #cc092f;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.bs-pagination a:first-child {
margin-left: 10px;
}

ul.bs-pagination a:hover {
    border-color: #cc092f;
}
```

```html
<nav class="bs-pagination__nav" aria-label="Paginação">
  <ul class="bs-pagination">1<a href="#link" title="Link para a página 2" id="#some-id">2</a><a href="#link" title="Link para a página 3" id="pc1617018954514_linkToPage_3">3</a> </ul>
</nav>
```

Frankly speaking if you can't put your links inside `<li> </li>`, you should change your ul to div like below:

```css
div.bs-pagination {
        font-weight: 500;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin: 0px 2px;
        min-width: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    div.bs-pagination a {
        padding: 0 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #cc092f;
        transition: 0.3s;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    div.bs-pagination a:first-child {
    margin-left: 10px;
    }

    div.bs-pagination a:hover {
        border-color: #cc092f;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="bs-pagination__nav" aria-label="Paginação">
      <div class="bs-pagination">1<a href="#link" title="Link para a página 2" id="#some-id">2</a><a href="#link" title="Link para a página 3" id="pc1617018954514_linkToPage_3">3</a> </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Yep, you can select the parent element of your text, but if you want use this way with parent class don't forget about order ul.your-class{the styles}

Comment: @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .bs-pagination > * {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
    }
}
.bs-pagination > * {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    min-width: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.bs-pagination a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #cc092f;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
/* TEST CUSTOMIZE UL */
.bs-pagination ul {
    color: #cc092f;
}

Comment: I told you, that you should remeber about elements ordering : ul.bs-pagination { color: #cc092f; } or ul.bs-pagination { color: #cc092f !important; }. First you should use html tag of element like ul and the next a class of this element: <ul class="my-class"></ul> should be written in css like this: ul.my-class {color: red;}

Comment: yanca I edited the post, what happens, that when I use ul directly to apply the customizations it ends up that it doesn't give the proper paddings

Comment: Add your paddings to link, not to ul. ul.bs-pagination a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #cc092f;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0px 10px;
}

Comment: Yes, I already applied the way you said but without success, I updated the css and put an example image in the post

Comment: Look at my code, I put there another one styles for first link of your pagination with a margin. Compare your code with mine and you'll see differences.

Comment: Frankly being on your place I would think about rebuilding the pagination structure, because like someone here said, it's not a good way to wrap links directly by list wrapper. I would do it like this <nav>Page 1 <a href="#link">Page 2</a><a href="#link">Page 3</a></nav> or with ul <nav><ul><li>1</li><li><a href="#link">Page 2</a></li><li><a href="#link">Page 3</a></li></ul>

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your HTML code is not correct. You are changing the semantics of HTML elements. The whole purpose of developing HTML is to describe the semantic element of the documents.

According to [HTML Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element), the only children of ul element is li element.

```
<ul>
 <li>Norway</li>
 <li>Switzerland</li>
 <li>United Kingdom</li>
 <li>United States</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So I can't insert the li, because the creation of these elements inside the ul is dynamic. I only created ul to facilitate the organization

Comment: Make a different list of items for pagination numbers and pagination content.